# Hibernate annotation error(as i understand it couldn't locate needed class)

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I dont get where the real problem is.When i ma trying to move to my class from cfg.xml it works fine.So i can say is "can see" my classes.If so where is the problem. Btw its a jax-ws service.Maybe its changes something. 
Question is what should i do to fix this problem?
All the logs and listing are provided below.If you will have any questions comment.

Configuration methods invoke listing:

```
@Override
public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    User user = new User(1,"1","1",1,"1");
    List<Bids> bids = new ArrayList<Bids>();
    bids.add(new Bids(user, 1, "2","3"));
    bids.add(new Bids(user, 1, "4","5"));
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return "data";
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="sureName")
    private String sureName;

    @Column(name="creditCardNumber")
    private int creditCardNumber;

    @Column(name="phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Bids> bids; 

    User(int id,String name, String sureName, int creditCardNumber, String phoneNumber){
    this.Id = id;
    this.sureName = sureName;
    this.Name = name;
    this.creditCardNumber = creditCardNumber;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
```

Cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auction_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">3070409j</property>

    <mapping class="helloworld.User"/>
    <mapping class="helloworld.Bids"/>
    <mapping class="helloworld.Aucton"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Log:

```
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2 cr4
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ноя 05, 2015 8:15:21 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="helloworld.User"/>
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="helloworld.User"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1479)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1352)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1338)
    at helloworld.HelloWorldImpl.getHelloWorldAsString(HelloWorldImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:68)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:73)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1035)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1004)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:862)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:404)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:706)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:82)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When i am changing configuration creation to :
Error changes to :

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .configure().buildSessionFactory();

ноя 05, 2015 8:40:33 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
    SEVERE: Implementing class
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    at ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In getHelloWorldAsString() method build a session factory like this

```
 sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

It should solve your issue

Comment: Try cleaning up your code and deploy it again... the error says that it is looking for an AnnotationConfiguration instance and what I told you creates an instance of the same. I think it should work.

Comment: This link explains similar configurations as yours - see if anything else is missing - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html

Comment: Everything looks fine.But error still remains.When i am changing my default session creation method it still says: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class.Even with api  /

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in difference of jar versions.So i just downloaded all the up to date libs and it works now.